# Add new row in existing Excel file not saving data

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm trying to save new row in already existing xlsx file but nothing happening, it's not saving anything in it. Following is my code:

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("report.xlsx");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()+1;

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$row, $_POST['anonymous']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$row, $_POST['pdoStaff']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$row, $_POST['mu_number']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$row, $_POST['full_name']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$row, $_POST['nationality']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$row, $_POST['email']);

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('report.xlsx');
```

Comment: Check whether `$_POST` contains anything.

Comment: @TobiasF. yes it does.

Comment: Then try to turn on error reporting.

Comment: So where are you writing a new row? the code only shows you writing to row 1. Is that what you mean to do? What is in row 1 already?